# Error on Restler response in Restangular

Tags: php, api, rest, restler, restangular

I've been at this for a couple days and can't seem to get this to work.  My issue is that I'm using Restler (version 3) for an API and Restangular on my front end and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: can't convert undefined to object restangularizeBase@http://localhost/vendor/restangular/src/restangular.js:436 restangularizeCollection@http://localhost/vendor/restangular/src/restangular.js:552 createServiceForConfiguration/fetchFunction/<@http://localhost/vendor/restangular/src/restangular.js:610 Qc/e/j.promise.then/h@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:78 Qc/g/<.then/<@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:78 e.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:88 e.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:86 e.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:88 e@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:95 p@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:98 Yc/</t.onreadystatechange@http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:99
```

Here are the relevant code snippets that so you can see what I'm doing:

*Restler setup to set up my API*

```
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('User');
$r->handle();
```

*User class object I'll be accessing for my API (for now I'm just returning an example for testing)*

```
class User{
    public function index() {
        return  array(
            array(
                'first_name'=>'John',
                'last_name'=>'Smith',
                'role'=>'supervisor',
            ),
            array(
                'first_name'=>'Matt',
                'last_name'=>'Doe',
                'role'=>'employee',
            ),

        );
    }
}
```

Finally my app.js file

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('cma',['restangular']);

app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');
    RestangularProvider.setExtraFields(['name']);
    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response,operation) {
        return response.data;
    });
});

app.run(['$rootScope','Restangular',function($rootScope,Restangular) {
    var userResource = Restangular.all('session');
    $scope.test = userResource.getList(); // This is where the error is happening 
}]);
```

The API is returning the following JSON response (taken from Firebug:

```
GET http://localhost/api/user 200 OK 96ms
```

):

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "role": "supervisor"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Matt",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "role": "employee"
    }
]
```

I can't see anything that is going on that would be causing an issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of Restangular :)

The problem is that you're using a responseInterceptor and actually returning an array.

So, your server is returning an array. Your responseInterceptor gets it and then returns the `data` variable of your array. As that's undefined, undefined is sent to Restangular and therefore you get that error.

Remove the responseInterceptor and everything will start working :).

Bests